# Use jQuery Dialog in href tags that are generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jquery-ui

So I have a dynamically generated table, on the last row of the table is a href with the unique ID of each person on the database, and it's under a hyperlink so that I can gather the ID of the person, transfer it to another page and see the details of the person associated to a specific ID. The href points towards `admin_edit.php`, this is the page where the hyperlink directs the unique ID to. Now in its current state after you click on the hyperlink it will physically go to the page. But I want the page to show up in the jQuery Dialog box. Now I've done this sort of thing before, but with buttons. For some reason I'm unable to implement this in the form of hyperlinks.

**My HTML/PHP/AngularJS code:**
`

```
<div>
       <table>
               <tbody>                 
                <tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">
                    <td>{{data.first_name}} {{data.last_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.team_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.role}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.phone}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.to_date}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.email}}</td>
                    <td><a id="modifyLink" href="admin/admin_edit.php?id={{data.id}}">{{data.id}}</a></td>   
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>        
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems == 0">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h4>No data found</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems > 0">    
            <div pagination="" page="currentPage" on-select-page="setPage(page)" boundary-links="true" total-items="filteredItems" items-per-page="entryLimit" class="pagination-small" previous-text="&laquo;" next-text="&raquo;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="modify" class="divider"></div> `
```

**My jQuery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
         var dlg=$('#modify').dialog({
           title: 'Modify',
           resizable: true,
           autoOpen:false,
           modal: true,
           hide: 'fade',
           width:600,
           height:500
         });


         $('#modifyLink').click(function(e) {
           dlg.load('admin/admin_edit.php');
           e.preventDefault();
           dlg.dialog('open');
        }); 
});
```

How do I get the hyperlinks to open in `admin_edit.php` in a dialog box instead of going to the physical URL?

Comment: You give your `<a>` an ID and call that ID`.load` on `click` event to the php page, passing something like `dlg.load('admin/admin_edit.php?id='+id)`

Comment: Can you provide code solution?

Comment: Nope, that's not what SO is for. But I provided you the path, which with some research efforts, can guide you to the code you want. :)

Comment: Of course, other people will just ignore that and give you full code answers to your problems anyway sometimes, but that's another subject.

Comment: ah okay, as long as you don't get impatient, well the thing is the dialog box won't even open. And I don't understand why because on the same page I have the same setup but the dialog box is linked to buttons, and it works perfectly this way. I've applied similar structure to the hyperlinks but the dialog box won't even open. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong/

Comment: We are members of a helping and support community, we're *expected* to be very patient so don't worry about it :) Now, you say you have buttons that work with this code, but I can't see them on your code (neither HTML nor JS have references to them), can you show us?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, here is a paste of the HTML button code alongside the AngularJS code to achieve dialog functionality: https://paste.ee/p/vKqBx

Comment: Are you defining `var dlg` on the same page? Or those scripts are at different files?

Comment: Try this: remove `admin/admin_edit.php?id={{data.id}}` from your `href`, change it to `#`, and put `admin/admin_edit.php?id={{data.id}}` inside `dlg.load('admin/admin_edit.php');` like `dlg.load('admin/admin_edit.php?id='+id);` (and don't forget to declare `id` before it). Keep everything else the way it is.

Comment: Thanks, gave it a try but still no luck :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```js
$(function() {
    $("a").click(function(e) {
        // Prevent default
        e.preventDefault();
        
        // Grab the url and do what you want with it
        alert($(this).attr("href"));
        
        // Grab the custom attribute
        alert($(this).data("id"));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="//raw.githubusercontent.com/xxxmatko/xDev.RequireJs/master/README.md" data-id="test" target="_blank">link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using angular, use `ng-click` instead of using a jQuery `onClick`. Then you can pass the `data.id` to a function in your `$scope`.

```
<a href ng-click="showDialog(data.id);" id="modifyLink">{{data.id}}</a>
```

Then in your angular controller, create the `showDialog` function to do the same thing your jQuery `onClick` was doing.

```
$scope.showDialog = function(id) {
    var dlg=$('#modify').dialog({
        title: 'Modify',
        resizable: true,
        autoOpen:false,
        modal: true,
        hide: 'fade',
        width:600,
        height:500
    });
    dlg.load('admin/admin_edit.php?id='+id);
    dlg.dialog('open');
};
```

Comment: Gave this a try but it's not opening any dialog boxes or even redirecting to `admin_edit.php`

Comment: Did you put the `$scope.showDialog` method in a controller?

Comment: I copied the AngularJS code, I'm extremely new to AngularJS so I'm not quite sure what a controller is

Comment: How is your `list` getting populated with data? That would have to be in some kind of controller for it to be accessible on your page.